# Fastest way to search for an object in a list in java

Tags: java, search, parallel-processing, hashmap

I have a structure:

```
public class DataItem {
    public int wordID, categoryID, documentID, count;
}
```

I have a list of it like below:

```
final public ArrayList<DataItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have written a method to search inside it:

```
public DataItem FindDataItem(final int wordID, final int categoryID, final int documentID)
{
    for(DataItem dataItem : data)
        if(dataItem.wordID == wordID && dataItem.documentID == documentID && dataItem.categoryID == categoryID)
            return dataItem;
    return null;
}
```

But it is so slow. How can I speed it up?

I am thinking of four **HashMap**s inside each other but I want to use this data like a database table so it is hard to do group by count in **HashMap**

I am also thinking about **ParalellStream** but I don't know how to use it. Looks complicated. but it is still O(n).

I am thinking about using a database too. But I don't want to have IO. I want it all inside RAM.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: `I am thinking about using a database too. But I don't want to have IO. I want it all inside RAM.` You could use SQLite then, it's DB-on-file, the usage is the same as any other db except you don't have any real connections between a client and a server.

Comment: @BackSlash It has IO.

Comment: Best is HashMap<List> as get(object) can be found in constant time...

Comment: The OP array can contain more than one dataItem with the same values. Her find algo just returns the first one. If you are using a hash map based on the values of the dataItem then duplicates are not allowed, resp. are discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ShreyasSarvothama says in the comments, the fastest way to retrieve values would be using a Map.

I think you could use a map whose keys are calculated with the values you use as parameters of your find method (taking into account that the combination of them gives a unique identifier of a DataItem).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {

    private class DataItem {
        public int wordID, categoryID, documentID, count;

        public DataItem(int w, int c, int d) {
            wordID = w;
            categoryID = c;
            documentID = d;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "wordID:" + wordID + " categoryID:" + categoryID + " documentID:" + documentID;
        }
    }

    private Map<Integer, DataItem> map;

    public void setList(List<DataItem> list) {
        this.map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(dataItem -> dataItem.wordID * dataItem.categoryID * dataItem.documentID, dataItem -> dataItem));        
    }

    public DataItem getDataItem(int wordID, int categoryID, int documentID) {
        return map.get(wordID * categoryID * documentID);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setList(Arrays.asList(t.new DataItem(1,2,3), t.new DataItem(2,3,4), t.new DataItem(3,3,4)));
        System.out.println(t.getDataItem(2,3,4));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could use a parallel stream:

```
public DataItem FindDataItem(final int wordID, final int categoryID, final int documentID) {
    return data.parallelStream()
            .filter(dataItem -> dataItem.wordID == wordID
                    && dataItem.documentID == documentID
                    && dataItem.categoryID == categoryID)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Like you said, it won't affect the time complexity, but it can speed up the operation depending on the number of threads available.

Comment: Clarify me here please, isnt Hashmap get() returns in constant time.. does paralleStream also does it in constant time?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama My understanding is that OP wants to be able to query by a subset of keys (e.g. `(wordID, documentID)`), which doesn't scale well with a HashMap.